# Wrap set of elements in <div> tag

Tags: jquery

I've seen a few answers here on this but can't seem to make it work.

I have a set of repeatable HTML like this:

```
<div id="content">

<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>

</div>
```

Etc. this goes on infinitely based on the number of entries.

What I want to do is wrap every three sets of articles/divs in a div. So I would have:

```
<div id="content">

<div class="wrap">
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
<article>
<div>
</div>

</div>
```

I'm sure this is something easy, but for some reason I can't get it to work. Any and all help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.slice()` method:

```
var $e = $('#content').children();

for (var i = 0; i < $e.length; i+=3) {
  $e.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="wrap">');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @AnneSchmidt You are welcome, please note the below answer won't work. DOM doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

The `nth-child` selector is another alternative, but not as nice as undefined's solution:

```
 $('#content > article:nth-child(3n+1)').before('<div class="wrap">');
 $('#content > div:nth-child(3n+1)').after('</div>');
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the .slice() solution above, but I'll keep this in mind as well.